# Apple deprecated verifyReceipt, how we check for receipt status now

Tags: server, app-store, deprecated, storekit

I have question concerning the deprecated `verifyReceipt`. According to Apple, that endpoint will soon be deprecated and we are advised to use new Apple server API endpoint.

So my previous flow is:

- I call the `verifyReceipt` with the encoded receipt data
- get back the decoded value
- check the status and see if the receipt is valid or not

My updated flow without the `verifyReceipt` endpoint (I used appstoreserverlibrary for python https://github.com/apple/app-store-server-library-python?tab=readme-ov-file#usage)

- I establish the client using the `client = AppStoreServerAPIClient(private_key.encode('utf-8'), key_id, issuer_id, bundle_id, environment)`
- then I tried to get the transaction id from the receipt and then call `get_transaction_info`

  ```
  transaction_id_from_receipt = receipt_util.extract_transaction_id_from_app_receipt(app_receipt)
  response = client.get_transaction_info(transaction_id_from_receipt)
  ```

  But then I do not see how can we get the receipt status.

Does anyone know how can we obtain the receipt status with the new Apple server API?

And is my updated flow moving away from `verifyReceipt` above correct?

Comment: @Lee Hi not yet, I still looking around to see how to solve it.